# Explicit images sent by adults

Tags: australia, sexual-offences

I know that distribution and possession of any explicit images of children are illegal as it is child pornography. On the other hand, is it illegal for an adult to send explicit images of them to children in Australia? I know many countries charge the adult for obscenity, but what laws apply in this situation  for Australia? Please include sources.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/80095/35069 (and presumably by the same OP..?)

Comment: Related question: [Is it legal for a child to ask an adult for nudes?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79345/is-it-legal-for-a-child-to-ask-an-adult-for-nudes)

Comment: It depends on if it's done knowingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you send explicit images of yourself to a child, then the answer is yes.

You would be committing several offences.

For Safeguarding purposes, please don't send photos of yourself to children.

1. If image is unsolicited you could be charged under **Spam Act 2003**.
2. You could also be charged under section **218A of the Criminal Code 1899** for online grooming (if found to have coerced child into receiving photographs).